# How to use 'MinValueValidator' considering other model field?

Tags: django, django-models

How can I use `MinValueValidator` on a `DateField` based on another `DateField` on the same model class?

Example code:

`models.py` code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator

class Edition(models.Model):
    submission_deadline = models.DateField(
        'some text',
        help_text='some help text'
    )

    committee_evaluation_deadline = models.DateField(
        'some text',
        help_text='some help text',
        validators=[MinValueValidator(submission_deadline, message='some specific error message')]
    )

    scientific_editor_evaluation_deadline = models.DateField(
        'some text',
        help_text='some help text',
        validators=[MinValueValidator(committee_evaluation_deadline, message='some specific error message')]
    )

    appraiser_evaluation_deadline = models.DateField(
        'some text',
        help_text='some help text',
        validators=[MinValueValidator(scientific_editor_evaluation_deadline, message='some specific error message')]
    )

    author_correction_deadline = models.DateField(
        'some text',
        help_text='some help text',
        validators=[MinValueValidator(appraiser_evaluation_deadline, message='some specific error message')]
    )

    appraiser_revaluation_deadline = models.DateField(
        'some text',
        help_text='some help text',
        validators=[MinValueValidator(author_correction_deadline, message='some specific error message')]
    )

    # other fields that are excluded from the form
```

`form.py` code:

```
class EditionCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Edition
        exclude = ['magazine', 'slug', 'appraisers', 'types', 'published']
```

The form will handle save method, so all validators will be triggered. I guess there is another easy way to do this so I don't have to make field by field validation on form (clean_field()) or model save to raise especific error message for every field.

Anyone knows how to get the field value of DateField that can I use on my models' definition? I mean, I don't wanna to implement another line of code, **I just wanna to know if in this scenario there is a way to enjoy the built-in MinValueValidator that is already implemented just referencing other models' field**. I tested and if I use a hand coded condition, for exemple `datetime.date(2018, 10, 22)`, the form raises and render the field error perfectly whithot more code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use signals: pre_save() is recommended. You can check and verify those data before insert

Comment: Alberto, I edited my question to be more specif on how information I wanna to know. Basically, I wanna to know if there is a way to get the field' value without write more code. Do you know a way to do this?